# How to get hash of http content before downloading it?

Tags: c++, http, hash, download

I'm developing a Windows intranet application in C++ which needs to download a settings file from a predefined URL hosted on a webserver on the intranet.
This file would be updated every few weeks and I need to get it only if it has changed.

To avoid unnecessary downloads I wanted to know if there is a standard HTTP method to only request the hash of the file to the webserver to prevent a full download if the file has not changed.

I'm still in the design phase and the idea would be to use CURL library on the client to download the file and Apache as a webserver, but I'm also open to other solutions.

Comment: I don't think there's a standard hash function, but I'm curious why the "If-Modified-Since" header doesn't fit your needs?  Or for that matter an "ETag" which is opaque but might well be implemented as a hash?

Comment: I can also get the header only and use the Last-Modified header, but I wanted to rely on the hash of the file for better security